# filter and parse unstructured log with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash, kibana, grok

i'm pretty new to logstash and i have a problem.

I want to filter a line from a log that is different from others and then make some manipulation with grok.

This is the log file that i have:

```
Date: 3/1/2021 -- 05:08:14 (uptime: 2d, 22h 36m 18s)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Counter                                       | TM Name                   | Value
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
capture.kernel_packets                        | Total                     | 433066
capture.kernel_drops                          | Total                     | 18183
decoder.pkts                                  | Total                     | 414883
decoder.bytes                                 | Total                     | 453509832
decoder.ipv4                                  | Total                     | 413834
decoder.ipv6                                  | Total                     | 778
decoder.ethernet                              | Total                     | 414883
decoder.tcp                                   | Total                     | 409208
decoder.udp                                   | Total                     | 5266
decoder.icmpv6                                | Total                     | 56
decoder.avg_pkt_size                          | Total                     | 1093
decoder.max_pkt_size                          | Total                     | 1514
flow.tcp                                      | Total                     | 1273
flow.udp                                      | Total                     | 1336
flow.icmpv6                                   | Total                     | 26
flow.wrk.spare_sync_avg                       | Total                     | 100
flow.wrk.spare_sync                           | Total                     | 18
decoder.event.ipv4.opt_pad_required           | Total                     | 82
decoder.event.ipv6.zero_len_padn              | Total                     | 24
flow.wrk.flows_evicted_needs_work             | Total                     | 535
flow.wrk.flows_evicted_pkt_inject             | Total                     | 579
flow.wrk.flows_evicted                        | Total                     | 406
flow.wrk.flows_injected                       | Total                     | 535
tcp.sessions                                  | Total                     | 667
tcp.syn                                       | Total                     | 669
tcp.synack                                    | Total                     | 668
tcp.rst                                       | Total                     | 407
tcp.stream_depth_reached                      | Total                     | 14
tcp.reassembly_gap                            | Total                     | 8
tcp.overlap                                   | Total                     | 27
detect.alert                                  | Total                     | 1106
app_layer.flow.http                           | Total                     | 41
app_layer.tx.http                             | Total                     | 126
app_layer.flow.tls                            | Total                     | 611
app_layer.flow.ntp                            | Total                     | 15
app_layer.tx.ntp                              | Total                     | 15
app_layer.flow.dhcp                           | Total                     | 4
app_layer.tx.dhcp                             | Total                     | 6
app_layer.flow.dns_udp                        | Total                     | 964
app_layer.tx.dns_udp                          | Total                     | 1934
app_layer.flow.failed_udp                     | Total                     | 353
flow.mgr.full_hash_pass                       | Total                     | 35
flow.spare                                    | Total                     | 9856
flow.mgr.rows_maxlen                          | Total                     | 2
flow.mgr.flows_checked                        | Total                     | 3998
flow.mgr.flows_notimeout                      | Total                     | 1808
```

it is repeating starting from the date. i need only the date string and nothing more and then i want to make some manipulation on the data, to send them as json. There is a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

First, you must manage multiline. So I suppose you have input log file (you could change as you want the approach is the same).

```
input {
 file {
    path => ["inputlogs/*"]
    codec => multiline {
                   pattern => "^Date: %{DATE:date} -- %{TIME:time}"
                   negate => true
                   what => previous
    }       
 }
}
```

After this, you must filter each line (I guess csv filter must be more useful in this case, but we can handle this with grok too as you've asked) :

```
grok {
    match => ["message","^%{NOTSPACE:fieldname}\s*\| %{WORD:field}\s*\| %{INT:value}"]
}
```

All lines that don't match this pattern (header and -- line) are flaged with *_grokparsefailure*